# Как можно выполнять несколько задач одновременно в c#?

Tags: c#

Каким образом можно выполнять несколько задач одновременно? Например: выполняется цикл и одновременно выполняется еще один цикл.

Comment: Способов реализации много. Почитайте теорию о много-поточном программировании, и документацию к классам `Thread` и `Task`. В документации к этим классам есть достаточное количество рабочих примеров, которых с избытком хватит для начала.

Comment: Стартовая точка: [Parallel Programming in .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/). Конкретно по вашему вопросу: [Parallel.Invoke](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.invoke?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 3):

Clordrin.
Один из основных способов реализации одновременного выполнения нескольких задач - использование многопоточности. Для начала:

**1. Подключить namespace Threading.**

```
using System.Threading;
```

**2. Создать два потока и в скобочках указать имя метода, который должен выполняться в потоке.**

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(Function1); // Создаём поток 1
Thread thread2 = new Thread(Function2); // Создаём поток 2
```

**3. Создаём два метода и в них указываем цикл. В теле цикла выводим имя потока и 
 переменную для примера и указываем задержку патока**

```
static void Function1()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // Метод, который будет работать в потоке 1
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Поток 1 вывел - " + i);
        Thread.Sleep(1000); // Задержка на 1000мс
    }
}
static void Function2()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // Метод, который будет работать в потоке 2
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Поток 2 вывел - " + i);
        Thread.Sleep(1000); // Задержка на 1000мс
    }
}
```

**4. Запускаем потоки**

```
thread1.Start(); // Запуск потока 1
thread2.Start(); // Запуск потока 2
```

**Весь код программы:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace MultiThreadingQuestion
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread thread1 = new Thread(Function1); // Создаём поток 1
            thread1.Start(); // Запуск потока 1

            Thread thread2 = new Thread(Function2); // Создаём поток 2
            thread2.Start(); // Запуск потока 2

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static void Function1()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // Метод, который будет работать в потоке 1
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Поток 1 вывел - " + i);
                Thread.Sleep(1000); // Задержка на 1000мс
            }
        }
        static void Function2()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // Метод, который будет работать в потоке 2
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Поток 2 вывел - " + i);
                Thread.Sleep(1000); // Задержка на 1000мс
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Результат выполнения программы:**
[image: Результат выполнения программы]

Надеюсь этот ответ был вам полезен.

Comment: Никогда не приводите код скриншотом.

Comment: В C# не нужно дожидаться выполнения потоков (метод `join()`)? Или хотя бы демонизировать их, если программа допускает собственное завершение раньше окончания работы потоков?

Comment: Почему нельзя итоговый общий код скриншотом показывать?

Comment: Этика SO. Если человек захочет испробовать Ваш код, то он не сможет его просто скопировать.

Comment: Спасибо, в следующий раз учту.

Comment: Было бы хорошо, если бы Вы исправили свой ответ.

Comment: Также актуальны мои вопросы.